# Vimeo video not working with HTML5 tag

Tags: jquery, html, video, slider, vimeo

I want to add a slider to Vimeo videos. I checked [this slider](http://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-responsive-youtube-video-gallery/), but it uses the HTML5 video tag. When I use the same tag with a Vimeo video URL then it's not working. Here is my code:

```
<video src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/68866759"></video>
```

Here is the full code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://amazingslider.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/plugins/amazingslider-plugin/sharedengine/amazingslider.js?ver=1.6'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />
<div class="demo-slider">
    <div style="display:block;position:relative;margin:15px auto 30px;" id="amazingslider-11">
        <ul style="display:none;" class="amazingslider-slides">
            <li><img alt="Big Buck Bunny Copyright  Blender Foundation" src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/images/big_buck_bunny_480_270.jpg">
                <video src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/68866759" preload="none"></video>
            </li>
            <li><img alt="Elephants Dream Copyright  Blender Foundation" src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/images/elephants_dream_480_270.jpg">
                <video src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TLkA0RELQ1g" preload="none"></video>
            </li>
            <li><img alt="Sintel - Third Open Movie by Blender Foundation" src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/images/Sintel_480_270.jpg">
                <video src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eRsGyueVLvQ" preload="none"></video>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="display:none;" class="amazingslider-thumbnails">
            <li><img src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/images/thumbnails/big_buck_bunny_480_270.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/images/thumbnails/elephants_dream_480_270.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/images/thumbnails/Sintel_480_270.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="display:none;" class="amazingslider-engine"><a href="http://www.amazingslider.com">jQuery Slider</a></div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/11/sliderengine/initslider.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vimeo gives you a page to embed. Copy whatever HTML snippet Vimeo gives you and paste it in place of your `<video>`.

Answer (score 21):

Go to your **Video Settings** and **Video File**, at the bottom there is a section called **Use Your Own Player**, you'll find there direct urls to your video. Example:

```
<video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"></video>
```

Note: This requires a **PRO** Vimeo account.

Comment: Is there a way to find those direct urls for the video if you are not the content owner and just want to play Vimeo videos on a Video htnl5 tag on a webpage like the vimeo homepage for example or http://summitdublin.com/ ?

Comment: I can't find the "Use your own player", does it still existing or not ?

Comment: Take a look: https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#do-custom-embed-settings-work-with-third-party-players - Only PRO members can embed videos in custom/third-party players.

Comment: Does this really requires a PRO Vimeo account?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use our embed code for it to work. http://player.vimeo.com/video/68866759 is not a video file, it's an HTML page, so putting it in a video tag won't do anything.

If you replace the video tag with this it should work:

`<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/68866759" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`