# Can I embed videos from Vimeo into my own website using HTML5 video tag?

Tags: html, video, vimeo

In case I can, would anyone give me one little example? I'd be highly grateful.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426410/vimeo-video-not-working-with-html5-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"></video>
```

Comment: Cool! It works pretty well. But the problem is that mostly Vimeo videos URL are in the form "https://vimeo.com/51744154". And I replaced your this number "85569724" with "51744154" of my URL and the rest of the address was left unaltered but it didn't work. How am I supposed to deal with this?