# How do I embed a Vimeo video without the Vimeo player?

Tags: stream, vimeo, vimeo-api

I couldn't find a proper explaination, tutorial or thread online explaining the following: I "simply" want to load a Vimeo Video (where I have a pro-Account) without controls (play, pause, timeline, whatsoever) just the pure video (also without the black bar top and bottom) and stream it within a `div` I created. I want the video to be always fully filling this div.

How can I use the Vimeo-API to do that? I found examples of the Vimeo-API but nowhere I could find anything regarding loading the plain video file.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? When I Google `vimeo embed without controls` there seem to be plenty of instructions on how to remove the controls. Are they not working? Which approach did you use?

Comment: Well, I can't find a single ressource on how to load the video-file via pure javascript into a container. It always has to be done with embed code or something. I want to load the plain video file.

Comment: A `div` can't play a video - you'll always need *some* kind of element that can. This looks like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21550559/187606

Comment: I made a suggestion to edit the title

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550559/187606), your Vimeo videos should have a "play in external player" link (Pro account required):

> Go to your **Video Settings** and **Video File**, at the bottom there is a section called **Use Your Own Player**, you'll find there direct urls to your video.

You can embed that direct URL in a player of your choice - e.g. a `<video>` element:

```
<video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"></video>
```

You can create that `<video>` element using JavaScript, as well.

A plain `<div>` element can not dispplay video without some element to aid it.

Comment: These urls are also accessible via the Vimeo API inside the body of any request made to a video endpoint you own (such as https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos)